# Why does pgfmathsetmacro fail when using output from the lengthconvert package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, convert

I'm trying to draw rectangles that will scale based on `\textwidth`.  The scale functionality of `\begin{tikzpicture}` works great, but in that environment I'd like to work with centimetres instead of points.  If I hard-code the conversion in a `\newcommand*` things work fine.  If I try to derive the factor using the lengthconvert package it errors out.

Reproducer:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,verbose,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lengthconvert}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\lettertextwidthpt}{557.38951pt}%
%\newcommand*{\lettertextwidthcm}{\Convert[unit=cm,number-only]{\lettertextwidthpt}}% This fails.
\newcommand*{\lettertextwidthcm}{19.59}% This succeeds.

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\textwidth / \lettertextwidthpt]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\maxbits}{64}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\bitwidthcm}{\lettertextwidthcm / \maxbits}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@ 
                                                  
l.15 ...bitwidthcm}{\lettertextwidthcm / \maxbits}
```

While I'd like to know why this is failing, I'd also like to know how to identify the undefined control sequence and what I should have Googled to find the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. Google `expansion`. The pgfparsing routine is choking on all the `{` and `}` being used inside the `\Convert` function (in effect, a mini-program). Indeed, even a plain `[scale=\textwidth / 19.59{cm}]` fails, and `[scale=\textwidth / 19.59cm]` works.

Comment: @Cicada Ok, I'll buy that.  If you want to convert your observation into an answer I'll mark it as preferred.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Outcome is I've just M'ed the MWE, is all. I don't know enough about Tikz\pgf to say if that is a symptom or a cause (or a bug or intentional design), or what the workaround should look like; nor enough about expansion to get an expand-once result into that slot (via a `\foreach` construct, say), or maybe a calc in expl3 (actually, a lua calc might work, with only the result going back to Tex). There should be a way. You can self-answer and self-accept, if you're satisfied with things.  Perhaps wait a day or two, for someone more knowledgeable to see the question.

Comment: Another way might be via an `if`/`case`, if the set of combinations is small/finite. And have that go into the `scale=` (or into a separate tikz code block for each branch).

Answer (score 1):

You are lucky because sometimes you can use units in pgfmath.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\lettertextwidthpt}{557.38951pt}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\lettertextwidthcm{\lettertextwidthpt/1cm}

\begin{document}

\lettertextwidthcm %%% shows 19.59001

\end{document}
```

The doc does not guarantee that this works, though.